# VB 2010 Excel Automation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, vba, datagridview, selectionchanged

I'm trying to automate the filling of a master excel file from selected rows in a datagridview element. I've already hooked up the database to the datagrid and I am attempting to populate certain fields in the excel spreadsheet, based on selected row(s) of the data grid.

```
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    objExcel.Workbooks.Add("path of master workbook")
    '
    objExcel.Visible = True

    'Select and modify cells 

    'Site(Name)

    objExcel.Range("B2").Select()
    objExcel.ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1() = 'Where I want to specify the value
```

From the research I've done, I'll need to use the selectionchanged event of my datagrid to identify the selected rows, then populate the spreadsheet based on the column index, then use a loop for the remaining fields to populate. I'd also like to add the ability to create multiple sheets, by looping through the selected rows in the datagrid view.

I've looked at many different code samples for exporting the entire datagrid to Excel, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to obtain the value of only the selected row, and then further the individual cell values based on column.

Can someone point me in the right direction, or just let me know that I'm completely off base?

Comment: You are on the right track. You can use the `DataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event to get the details of the current row. See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged.aspx For interacting with Excel form VB.Net once you have the datagrid values, see this link http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/vb-net-and-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the value of a cell you can just use

```
objExcel.Range("B2").Value = "whatever"
```

There's no need to select a cell to set its value. 
Since you're going to be looping through rows/columns and inserting values, you may find it's more convenient to use a different approach to addressing specific cells:

```
objExcel.Cells(2,2).Value = "whatever"  'row,column
```

I'm not sure you need to capture events on your datagridview (unless you're automatically writing rows as they're being selected): i'm guessing you have a button or something to trigger the export, so all you need to dso is look at the dgv's `SelectedRows`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx#Y0

Comment: OK so to clarify a bit of what I'm trying to do... I have a datagrid filled with a list of locations with fields such as ID, Name, Address, etc. Based on the selected rows I would like the sheet to be populated with the values in each column. I'm struggling with the "whatever" value. I want "whatever" to be a cell value from the selected row of the datagrid. Something like objExcel.Cells(2,2).Value = DataGridListView1.SelectedRows() ? How could I pick out a unique cell based on column index from the "SelectedRows"? And also thank you much for the help so far, obviously I am a noob :-)

Comment: Reviewing code examples when they are setting the datagrid or excel sheet to static values makes sense to me, I'm just missing something major when it comes to working with the datagrid